# check NSString variable for NSDictionary value [NSNull null]

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary, xmlwriter

I am creating a XML with xmlWriter, I have values in an NSDictionary that has several key/value pairs, however some of these values are [NSNull null], I pass every value into its own NSString.

In my XMLWriter method I have an if statment that checks if this is a particular method call to the db if it is then I would like to create writeAttributes only for the NSString variables that are not equal too [NSNull null].

I am not sure how to dynamically check each variable.. I thought maybe I could do an if statment but thats not going to work because as soon as one of the variables dose not equal [NSNull null] then its going to jump out of this part of the XMLWritter when there might be more variables that are needed for the xml.

This is the failed Idea that I had so you understand what I am trying to do

```
// Method Params --->
- (NSMutableData *) addMethodParams
{  
    //allocate serializer (this is using the xmlWriter class)
    id <XMLStreamWriter> xmlWriter = [[XMLWriter alloc] init];
    [xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Eng"];
        [xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Parameters"];
            [xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Vars"];
    if ([methodName isEqualToString:@"SeriesSearch"]) // name of method currently being requested
    {
        if ((NSNull *) Series != [NSNull null]) { // if this is null then its jumped
            [xmlWriter writeAttribute:@"Code" value:Series];
        }
        else if ((NSNull *) IDSeries != [NSNull null]){ //if this is !null then it enters the if statement however it then will jump out and not check over any of the other if statments
            [xmlWriter writeAttribute:@"ManufacturerID" value:IDSeries]; 
        }
        //..


    }
            [xmlWriter writeEndElement];
        [xmlWriter writeEndElement];
    [xmlWriter writeEndElement];
```

So the question is how can I add the variables that have values into my xml the stop the variables that are null? to create I guess a sort of dynamic xml writer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, when you have to write the same code more than twice (or even more than once), you should think about creating a method or function.  So you could write a method like this:

```
- (void)writeAttribute:(NSString *)name ifNonNullValue:(id)value toWriter:(id<XMLStreamWriter>)writer {
    if (value != [NSNull null]) {
        [writer writeAttribute:name value:value];
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
[self writeAttribute:@"Code" ifNonNullValue:Series toWriter:xmlWriter];
[self writeAttribute:@"ManufacturerID" ifNonNullValue:IDSeries toWriter:xmlWriter];
...
```

You could also consider adding a category to `XMLWriter`.  A category lets you add your own methods to any class.  So you could add a category like this:

```
// XMLWriter+NonNull.h

#import "XMLWriter.h"

@interface XMLWriter (NonNull)

- (void)writeAttribute:(NSString *)name ifNonNullValue:(id)value;

@end

// XMLWriter+NonNull.m

@implementation XMLWriter (NonNull)

- (void)writeAttribute:(NSString *)name ifNonNullValue:(id)value {
    if (value != [NSNull null]) {
        [self writeAttribute:name value:value];
    }
}

@end
```

and use it like this:

```
// At top of file
#import "XMLWriter+NonNull.h"

...
    [xmlWriter writeAttribute:@"Code" ifNonNullValue:Series];
    [xmlWriter writeAttribute:@"ManufacturerID" ifNonNullValue:IDSeries];
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the values come from the dictionary, you can set up a loop to write all attributes:

```
NSDictionary *keyToAttr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithValuesAndKeys:
    @"Code", @"Series", @"ManufacturerID", @"IDSeries", nil];

for (key in keyToAttr) {
    NSString *data = [dataDict objectForKey:key];
    if (data && ((NSNull*)data != [NSNull null])) {
        NSString *attrName = [keyToAttr objectForKey:key];
        [xmlWriter writeAttribute:attrName data]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, I was just woundering also if this is abit redundant as I have 18 variables I have to check.. is there another way I could do this or is this okay?

Comment: @HurkNburkS Since the values come from the dictionary, you can set up a loop to write them out, as long as there is a way to map the keys of these values in the dictionary to the attributes that you are writing.

Comment: @HurkNburkS I edited the answer to show how you can do it in a loop.

Comment: @HurkNburkS I'm wondering if the trick with the loop has worked for you?

Comment: yes it did work :) however the way I have already structured several other method calls not related to this ment the solution I have marked being more correct for my current situation, I'm sorry for not being able to mark yours as well however I did test it and it seemed to work well which is why I have clicked the up button thingy for you :) sorry for not getting back to you sooner.

Comment: @HurkNburkS Oh, do not worry about accepting an answer -- I was just curious if the suggestion worked, since you mentioned that you were going to try it. Good luck with your project!

Comment: ha! all good :) I always feel bad when there are two good options on to try.. but yes it worked fine however due to the fact I had to alter the way the data was being sent to my class which handles my db engine request it would have ment for my other request (which there are several) i would have had to change them to work, and also to make sense of what i was doing. So yea for several reasons I went with the above solution but i did try your solution out and it did work ;) thanks for taking the time to respond.